# Hyperauto for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, palantir-foundry

We integrated SAP with HyperAuto V2 that brings increased performance, including real-time streaming support, currently, HyperAuto V2 supports SAP data sources only. We will start with the integration of Salesforce and would like to use HyperautoV2 but as said it is only available for SAP, thus the question is wil Hyperauto V2 be available for Salesforce soon, anybody?

Answer (score 1):

HyperAuto V2 support for more sources (including Salesforce) is being actively worked on and a beta release is coming soon.

Please note that streaming from Salesforce isn't currently supported in the platform, so this specific feature won't exist on release of HyperAuto V2 support.